# Querying an Entity that has a varbinary field with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

When I try to query an entity that has a varbinary field in it I am getting error:

"The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Here is my query:

```
Dim query = From entity In db.Entity
        Where entity.Id= Id          
        Select entity.VarBinaryField

 If query.FirstOrDefault IsNot Nothing Then

     bytes = query.First.ToArray

     Return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test")

 End If
```

The error gets generated when I check that the query isNot nothing.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `entity.VarBinaryField` (in your model class, not in the database)? I'm wondering why you apply `ToArray`. BTW: You are running the query twice (`FirstOrDefault` and `First` both hit the database). Better do: `x = query.FirstOrDefault if x InNot Nothing Do something with x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few other parameters in my linq query that I didn't include... Parameters were being pulled from the array which was throwing the error not the varbinary field...